# EOSIO_ABI macro problem on MacOS, can't use for contract implementations

Tags: eosiocpp, eosio.cdt

I have been fighting a bit with the `EOSIO_ABI` macro in C++. I am trying to implement a very simple Ping/Pong contract using the latest `eosio.cdt` tools installed on my machine.

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using eosio::name;
using eosio::print;

class ping_contract : public eosio::contract 
{
  public:
    using eosio::contract::contract;

    /// @abi action
    void ping(name receiver) {
        eosio::print("Pong from ", name{receiver});
    }
};

EOSIO_ABI(ping_contract, (ping))
```

It ends in the following error messages :

```
$ eosio-cpp -o tests/ping/ping.wasm tests/ping/ping.cpp --abigen

tests/ping/ping.cpp:19:27: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
EOSIO_ABI(ping_contract, (ping))
                      ^
tests/ping/ping.cpp:19:33: error: expected function body after function declarator
EOSIO_ABI(ping_contract, (ping))
                            ^
2 errors generated.
```

I tried out multiple syntax things, like using the `CONTRACT` keyword instead of `class`, or using the `ACTION` keyword in front of the `ping()` action.

There is actually 2 problems which I have here. First of all, it is required for me to write the ABI myself, then the real error, is about this EOSIO_ABI macro not functioning, as this is obviously the important part.

On another front, I have tested out using the `EOSIO_DISPATCH` macro instead of the `EOSIO_ABI` macro, with that one, the code compiles correctly. And I can also `cleos push action ...`. Yet, I don't see the `eosio::print` being executed. Though, I see a transaction appearing in blocks.

Please any help would be appreciated here :+1:

```
$ eosio-cpp -version
eosio-cpp version 1.3.2

$ g++ --version 
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
```

Have a great evening! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved ! I didn't go through the CHANGELOG for the latest 1.2 to 1.3 upgrade.

It turns out, the `EOSIO_ABI` macro has been renamed `EOSIO_DISPATCH` and so, it seems there is no problem with compilation on my machine.

One thing is remaining, but is linked to ABI generation, for which I took the decision to write it manually.

Comment: Where did you see this in the change log? I'm looking through the GitHub release history, but I don't see it.

Comment: hey there, you can see it here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt#eosiolibdispatcherhpp

Comment: if you want automatic ABI generation, look at the ACTION, CONTRACT, and TABLE macros in eosio.cdt.  They wil make sure your methods and tables are properly marked for inclusion in the ABI.